# BinarySearch - Replace a string element with another string element once found

Tags: arrays, string, struct, binary-search

How do I make a binary search replace an element of an array of strings with another element of an array of strings? This is the final part of my program and I don't get it...I know with char's you use strcpy, or .replace, etc.

I have a struct that has an "orginalWord" and a "replacementWord", then a string array of "inputword"'s, it takes the inputword, finds it within the struct array (comparing to the orginalWord), and once found (Which it does find it...that part works, it finds the correct element number, so I know the searching is correct) replaces the "inputword" with the "replacementword". I just can't make it replace the element within the "inputword" with the "reaplcementWord" it finds. Help please!! I'll post the Binarysearch function seperate from the rest of my code for easy of reading. I know this should be simple, but I can't remember for the life of me.

Example: So...searchitem is inputword[20] = "Like". Sruct Array... encryption[50].OrginalWord = "Like". Match found...encryption[50].ReplacementWord = "Ducks". I would like to put "Ducks" into inputword[20]. How would I do this using the BinarySearch?

```
//Function call within main:
for(number=0; number < plaincount; number++)
        { BinarySearch(encryption, count, inputword[number]);
         } 

int BinarySearch (StringPair correctword[], int size, string searchitem)
{   
    int middle =0, start = 0, last = size-1;
    bool found = false;
    int position = -1;
    while (!found && start <= last)
    { 
        middle = (start + last)/2; // Midpoint // Was a breakpoint here, why?
        if(correctword[middle].orginalWord == searchitem)
        {               
            position = middle;
            cout << "Replacing word: " << searchitem << " With: " << position << endl;

            searchitem.swap(correctword[position].replacementWord);

            found = true;
            return position; // Return new value for inputword array?
        }
        else if (correctword[middle].orginalWord < searchitem)
            { start = middle+1; }
        else last = middle-1;
    }
    cout << "Misspelled word found: " << searchitem << endl;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to make it so that searchitem is modified in the caller?

Comment: @VaughnCato Yes? Once it finds a match for the words, I want it to replace the element in the string array, that was used as the searchitem. With the string where it found the match at. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: I have a struct array of 2 strings, "OriginalWord" and "ReplacementWord". There's 86 of them. I then have a string array "inputword" of about 200. I use the "inputword" as the searchitem, searching within the struct array comparing to "OriginalWord", which it does find. But once it find it, I want it to take that element number in that array, and use "ReplacementWord" and put that new string, where the element within the string array for "intputword" is that was used as the search item.

Comment: So...searchitem is inputword[20] = "Like". Sruct Array... encryption[50].OrginalWord = "Like". Match found...encryption[50].ReplacementWord = "Ducks". I would like to put "Ducks" into inputword[20].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If searchitem is going to be modified, you need to pass it by reference:

```
int BinarySearch (StringPair correctword[], int size, string &searchitem)
```

Comment: That did it! Thank you!! It's replacing the words now!! Seems I must've went wrong somewhere else though, because only 80% of the words are being replace, but it works!! Thank you! :)